# Django invalid form when using modelchoicefield

Tags: django, forms

I am new to Django and I have been struggling to get the selected value of the `forms.ModelChoiceField` in my views. My form (post) is not valid and I noticed that the request.POST returns all the possible values in the ModelChoiceField. How do I get only model the selected by the user? Thank you in advance for any help.

**Model**

I have a sensor model as well as a measurements model...

```
class Sensor(models.Model):
    # This contains information about a sensor, type, location, and other
    type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ...

class Measurement(models.Model):
    #This contains the measurements of the sensors at a given date
    sensor = models.ForeignKey('Sensor')
    date = models.DateField()
    temperature = models.FloatField()
    pressure = models.FloatField()
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('sensor', 'date')
```

**Form**

... and a form that allows the user to choose the sensor and date:

```
class MeasurementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #the user is allowed to choose any sensor that is related to the measurement table
    sensor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sensor.objects.exclude(measurement=None))
    date =  forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(attrs={'format':'%Y-%m-%d'}), initial=datetime.today)
```

So far so good, this gets rendered by the get method and the user is able to select both sensor and date. However, the following view fails at the post, after submitting:

**Views**

```
class MeasurementView(View):
    form_class = MeasurementForm
    my_template = "measurement.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.my_template, {'form': form, 'data':None})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.POST)
        print(new_form.errors)
        new_form = self.form_class(data=request.POST)
        if new_form.is_valid():
            print('form is valid')
            data = get_data_for_sensor_date(
                        new_form.cleaned_data['sensor'],
                        new_form.cleaned_data['date']))
            return render(request, self.my_template, {'form':new_form, 'data':data})
        else:
            return render(request, self.my_template, {'form':new_form, 'data':None})
```

**Console output**

```
<QueryDict: {'sensor': ['', '1'], 
             'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['YUPfrdhdbQdAa7EyNx2sJeHdbxmQXTTW'], 
             'date': ['2016-11-07']}>

<ul class="errorlist">
  <li>__all__
    <ul class="errorlist nonfield">
      <li>Measurement with this Sensor and Date already exists.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. Editing the code as of now

Comment: How are you displaying the form in the template? Printing `request.POST` and `new_form.errors` in the `post` method might help explain what's going on.

Comment: Question updated to add the outcome of the printing. I do not get the error message. I know they exist and that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link [Django formview returns object already exists error with a modelform](https://recalll.co/app/?q=Django%20formview%20returns%20object%20already%20exists%20error%20with%20a%20modelform)

To which I quote:
"Ok. I found a solution for my error. What caused the model already exists error was my ModelForm CheckProductForm. Codename attribute is unique, so my validation always returned False. What I did was to change my orginal ModelForm to a Form. This solved my whole issue. And for the form_invalid in form_valid issue. I've overwritten my form's clean_codename function to raise ValidationError if product doesnt exist."

I still do not understand why I had the error in the first place. However, changing the form to the code below made the trick.

**Form**

```
class MeasurementForm(forms.Form):
    #the user is allowed to choose any sensor that is related to the measurement table
    sensor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sensor.objects.exclude(measurement=None))
    date =  forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(attrs={'format':'%Y-%m-%d'}), initial=datetime.today)
```

Comment: You have `unique_together = ('sensor', 'date')` for your model. That means that you can only have one measurement each day for each sensor. When you use a model form without setting `instance`, Django validates the unique constraint to prevent you from creating a duplicate measurement. Since you already have a measurement for that date and sensor in the database, the form is invalid and you get the error. Since you've switched to a regular form, the `unique_together` constraint is no longer checked, so the form is valid.

Comment: Thank you Alasdair. Having one measurement per day is the correct behaviour for my model. I was not aware that Django automatically performs the check at the form from the model, but it does make sense. Thank you.